# R not recognizing Excel cells populated with Bloomberg API code

Tags: r, excel, bloomberg

I have built a dynamically updating spreadsheet in Excel with BBG addin that pulls price data using BBG API. I am trying to pull a table from that sheet into R and create a simple scatterplot using the below code:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("Fx Vol Framework.xlsx")
data <- readWorksheet(wb,sheet = "Carry", region = "AL40:AN68",header=TRUE, rownames = 1)
plot(data,ylim = c(-2,12))
with(data,text(data, labels = row.names(data), pos = 1))
reg1 <- lm(data[,2]~data[,1])
abline(reg1)
```

The region I am calling (AL40:AN68) is populated with results from an HLOOKUP formula that calls from cells with BBG API. When I run the code, I get the below error (repeats the same error text for each cell):

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: Error when trying to evaluate cell AM41 - Name '_xll.BDP' is completely unknown in the current workbook
```

If I go back to the excel sheet and populate that same region AL40:AN68 with numeric values (copy -> paste values), save the workbook, and run the same code, I get the scatterplot I was expecting with the original code. Is there any way for me to get the scatterplot using the cells with Bloomberg API or do I need to run it with simple numeric values? Do I need the Bbg package for this to work? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach for other users now might be to use the [Rblpapi](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rblpapi) package from CRAN to connect to the Bloomberg API directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with BBG add in, but it seems like after calling readWorksheet you would want to call a function that actually opens the workbook. I think that would in a sense "complete the binding". At any rate I sometimes need to pass data between R and excel. Here is how I'd tackle the problem using the package **RDCOMClient**.

**R Code:**

```
library(RDCOMClient)

exB <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
book <- exB$Workbooks()$Open("C:/'the right directory/exp.xlsx'")

dNames <- book$Worksheets("Sheet1")$Range("AL40:AN40")
dValues <- book$Worksheets("Sheet1")$Range("AL41:AN68")

dNames <- unlist(dNames[["Value"]])
dValues <- unlist(dValues[["Value"]])

data1 <- matrix(dValues,ncol=3)
colnames(data1) <- dNames
data1 <- as.data.frame(data1)

plot(data1$v1,data1$v2)
```

Obviously you can plot things, model things or whatever in a number of ways, but this gets things into R which is probably the best place for it. At any rate there is also a good introduction to using the RDCOMClient package to connect R and Excel for quick data tasks at http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/Docs/introduction.html